# In Stargate: Universe, how come they have things like a shaver?

Tags: stargate, stargate-universe

The title pretty much says it all. They were evacuating a military base under attack to save their lives, and they thought that they were evacuating to Earth. Who would carry things like a shaver, a needle, gym clothes or who-knows-what-else? How come they have such things aboard Destiny? I doubt they would be present on the ship itself...

Did the creators of the show simply ignore this nonsense?

Comment: from my understanding some of them had just arrived on base/and/or were expecting to travel leave already so evacing with some bags that were already on hand, that could have contained items like this seems plausible

Comment: Good question, welcome to the site.

Comment: A good shaver is a fairly small expensive tool. And it makes you look presentable. Why in the world would you not grab it?

Comment: You can also break down a manual razor into some quite useful components. If you had the choice between packing something that could make you look sharp and something that is just sharp...I'd pack a razor

Comment: If they're in the military, I think they'd be out of uniform if they didn't keep their beards shaved (I think maybe mustaches are allowed), so it might be a higher priority than you'd think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

During the Pilot episode, as they evacuate the base you can see a number of crates and boxes of supplies come through the gate behind them.

[image]

I think we can assume that these boxes contain your mystery shaver and various other fripperies such as food.

---

This is backed up by the episode's [official novelisation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006GFXKZK) (which was itself based on the [show script](http://www.gateworld.net/universe/s1/transcripts/101.shtml))

> Young didn’t press the point and turned back to the lieutenant. **Make
>   sure that everyone carries as much of the expedition supplies as they
>   can.**
>
> Scott gave him a questioning look. Why?
>
> You’re not going to Earth. Rush dialed the ninth chevron.

and

> Young saw the chaos at the mouth of the gate and shouted at the top of
>   his lungs, snarling at the evacuees to get through as quickly as they
>   could. The gate room and Icarus itself was coming apart as chunks of
>   concrete and rebar fell from the ceiling, smashing through gantries
>   where they landed. Control panels sparked and dimmed as power began to
>   die off through the base’s crippled systems, and the colonel knew that
>   the death knell was only seconds away.
>
> Greer was almost at the event horizon, supporting an injured civilian
>   with his free hand. He caught sight of his commander and called out.
>   Sir!
>
> Young stabbed a finger toward the Stargate. Go! he shouted, and
>   reluctantly the Marine obeyed.
>
> **Dozens of supply cases and backpacks were scattered across the floor,
>   left behind by the fleeing evacuees, some too heavy to carry, others
>   broken open with their contents scattered.** He looked up to see the
>   last few people passing through the gate, and Young halted, instead
>   turning to the crates and starting a frantic search.

Comment: Apparently, those boxes also contained dozens of sets of gym clothes that we see everybody wearing a few episodes later. But no regular clothes, so you've got to wear the same thing you arrived wearing for the next two years!

Comment: @Thunderforge: Yes, the sports clothes! I forgot about them, but since they seem to be even more unbelievable than the shaver/needle, I'll add them to the question. Thank you.

Comment: @Richard: Good answer. I forgot about the amount of supplies they had brought, so I guess it *could happen* that they have this or that there, even though some of the things - like the gym clothes - still stretch it a bit too far (pun intended).

Comment: I suppose one could also fashion a type of straight edge blade/knife from a strip of metal lying around the ship and shave that way, a la the cowboy times.